# Firewall blocks all internet sharing except port 80

Tags: firewall, internet-sharing

MacBook Pro on 10.7.5 (Lion)
static ip 192.168.10.5 using wireless connection
ethernet jack connected to raspberry pi
raspberry pi has static ip 192.168.2.3

when internet sharing is enabled and firewall is enabled
-raspberry pi can surf the internet through browser
-terminal cannot ping macbook, cannot ping any ip on internet
-macbook can ping raspberry pi

when firewall is disabled
-terminal can ping macbook, can ping any address on internet

When internet sharing is turned on, is it ONLY sharing port 80?
How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I think it's a bit far-fetched to conclude form the fact that a ping does not work that nothing but port 80 works. Have you tried connecting to any other "useful" port, e.g. 53 on a DNS server or 25 on a mail server? Many firewalls block ICMP traffic to pevent simple network scans from detecting live hosts.

Comment: you're right. I had to disable stealth mode on mac firewall to allow pi to ping mac. All other functions work well (wget, curl, sudo apt-get, etc). Thank you for shaking me awake politely. I feel like Curly of the three stooges

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable stealth mode on mac firewall to allow pi to ping mac.